# Going from an array to object and creating subclasses

Tags: arrays, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner in google app script and would like to ask a question regarding how to create subclasses for an object based on an array of information drawn from my spreadsheet.

Here is an example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nppM0DzrQ9g28gqFJKjqtffL-fNwMwySUYenTyuPeeE/edit?usp=sharing) with some data in the sheet "History". The input data is the transactional history of the investment of a user. My end goal is to create an array inside google app script with adjusted stock-split values for any given stock.

However, the first step in my project would be to gather the data in such a manner that I can perform these calculations. For this, I would need to create an object such as this:

```
stock symbol: {date:value, {quantity: value, price:value}}, {date:value, {split ratio:value}}
```

The reason for this is because in this object the dates are linked to quantity price and split ratio. In later calculations I would look if the date of the split value is less or equal to the date of the quantity/price value, if this is true then perform split ratio * quantity and price/split ratio. If this is not true, then leave the price and quantity as is, for any given stock. Finally return these object in the same form as the orginal array.

This is the attempt I have made so far:

```
function createDate(date, quantity, price) {
  this.date = date;
  this.quantityPrice = new createDateData (quantity, price);
}

function createDateData(quantity, price) {
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.price = price;
}

function retrieveData () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  const data = inputSheet.getRange(2, 1, inputSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 9).getValues();
  const filterd = data.filter(row => row[2] == 'Buy' || row[2] == 'Sell' || row [2] == 'Split');
  const sorted = filterd.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1
    else return 0
  })
 for ( let i of sorted) {
var sampleData= new createDate([i][0][0],[i][0][3],[i][0][4]);
console.log(sampleData);
 }
}
```

This is the output I get

```
    { date: Tue Jun 30 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  quantityPrice: { quantity: 1, price: 40000 } }
```

Which is different than from the desired output?

Question: How do I get the desired output? For example, in the case of AMZN:

```
AMZN: {9/28/2020, {1, 100}}, {9/28/2020, {0.5, 200}}, {10/19/2020 {0.2, 100}}, {11/27/2020, {10}}
```

EDIT2: Please see sheet "Desired Output" for desired output.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `Question: How do I get the desired output?`, what is `stock symbol: {date:value, {quantity: value, price:value}}, {date:value, {split ratio:value}}`? That is the string value? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thanks for the response I edited the question to show desired output. See edit.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Question: How do I get the desired output? For example, in the case of AMZN:`, I couldn't understand your goal. Because I think that `AMZN: {9/28/2020, {1, 100}}, {9/28/2020, {0.5, 200}}, {10/19/2020 {0.2, 100}}, {11/27/2020, {10}}` is not a JSON object. Do you want to retrieve it as the text value? I apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: Apologies if this is not an object. I wish to multiply the quantity*split ratio and price/split ratio if the date of the quantity & price is equal or less than the date of the split ratio. How would I do this then?

Comment: Since it looks that here aren't too much guys with financial background, perhaps it would be easier if you add the result sheet that contains the data after you make the desired calculations. I believe the task is extremely simply algorithmically (with or without objects). But the financial lingo makes impossible to understand your goal.

Comment: @YuriKhristich So I added a sheet "Desired Output" as you suggested. You can see that the quantity of AMZN is multiplied by 10 and the price per share is divided by 10. This is done for all transactions BEFORE the split, but not after the split. The number 10 is derived from the split ratio in cell I28. The idea is to make a dynamic script, this time it is AMZN but next time it could be a different stock. I hope I explained it well enough now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you have the array formula in column 'Price', so you need to update the column 'Quantity' only. The column 'Price' will updated automatically.

And are you sure that the line 27 in your desired output should change? I think it should not, since it's 'Cash', not 'AMZN'.

Try this code:

```
function main() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),9);
  var data  = range.getValues().reverse(); // reverse to iterate it from the top to the bottom

  for (var row in data) {
    var action = data[row][2];
    if (action != 'Split') continue;
    data = [...data.slice(0,row), ...update(data.slice(row))]; // update all rows below the 'Split' 
  }

  // get column 'Quantity' from the data and put it on the sheet
  var quantity = data.map(x => [x[3]]).reverse(); 
  sheet.getRange(3,4,data.length,1).setValues(quantity);
}


// the function takes rows, recalculates quantity and returns the updated rows

function update(data) {
  var security = data[0][1];
  var ratio    = data[0][8];

  // if the security is the same as in the first row,
  // and if the action is 'Buy' or 'Sell':
  // the price will be multiply by the ratio
  for (var row in data) {
    if (data[row][1] != security) continue;
    var action = data[row][2];
    if (['Buy','Sell'].includes(action)) data[row][3] *= ratio;
    try {if (row[+r+1][1] == 'Split') break} catch(e) {} // <-- updated line
  }

  return data;
}
```

The script implies that all the rows are sorted by date. Newest dates at the bottom, oldest dates at the top.

There is no any objects. I see no need for them. Probably it could be done another way, with objects.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me taking the time to write this script. It works perfect! I tried to check for robustness, for example, what would happen if AMZN had a stock split at a later date after the first stock split? I edited the orginal data and desired output. However, your script takes the latest split ratio and then multiplies all quantities against this ratio. But if there are 2 stock splits, the first ratio would have to apply to all stock up and till the date of the stock split and the second ratio for all stock splits after this date, etc. Would it be possible to program this also?

Comment: '_But if there are 2 stock splits..._' well, this is a new condition. It can be handle of course. I'll try to update the code soon. Probably it will just one more line in the code: after the line `if (['Buy','Sell']...` to break the loop if next row contains 'Split'

Comment: You can try it by yourself: add the line `try {if (row[+r+1][1] == 'Split') break} catch(e) {}` and see. I'm away from my desktop, I can't to test it right now. The `try/catch` is need because it can be the last row and there will no nex (r+1) row.

Comment: Much appreciate the effort. Will try your suggestion tommorow. Daughter is sick son my hands are tied today.

Comment: I just tried the updated line, looks like it does the work. I wish a speedy recovery to the kid, be well.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks, she seems better already. Bless you and have a good day.